# Can box.com files be viewed natively in the browser?

Tags: online-storage, box.com

Is it possible to view files, e.g. in HTML, text or Markdown format, natively in the browser when they are hosted on box.com?

I’ve seen the ["direct link"](https://community.box.com/t5/Collaboration-and-Sharing/Direct-Linking-To-A-File/ta-p/148) post on community.box.com, which pertains to *downloading* of files, and also the thread ["hosting a html static website"](https://community.box.com/t5/SMB-Forum/Hosting-a-html-static-website-using-Box/m-p/12082) which indicates that native viewing is not supported. But even if it’s not officially supported by box.com, is there a workaround URL scheme or similar?

For reference, Dropbox has the following URL scheme for files stored in public folders: `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/[userID]/[path]/[file]`. This allows me to host simple web sites on Dropbox, which I find very useful. However, my current client wants me to store my work on box.com, and I’m hoping to do this without losing much-needed functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the lack of feedback both here and on Box’ own forum, I take it that the answer is **No**.

Comment: @pnuts Thank you for following up. I don't want the preview, I want the browser to render the files natively.